# SSO protocols in cloud computing?

Tags: authentication, cloud, single-sign-on, josso

As I know, there are several SSO protocols in the cloud authentication, they are openid, microid, josso, webauth, sourceID, cosign and Kerberos. Does it exist any other authentication protocols or structures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several others, including:

- [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)
- [Windows Live ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_ID)
- [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/)

Big list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations

Comment: OAuth isn't really an SSO protocol, although you could leverage it as plumbing for one.  OpenID Connect (http://openid.net/connect/) is an emerging standard that does just that.